# How to pass 3 dimensional value to vba and use it

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I need to find certain value (Value) in array.
Here is sample category (CAT) table:

```
CAT MIN MAX
1   0   10
2   10  40
3   40  80
```

Then input Value table sample is:

```
VAL CAT
42  
16  
2
```

I need to find CAT from CAT table for each VAL where VAL is between MIN and MAX, e.g. in Excel it looks like this:

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSuKC.jpg)

But I need to make it in VBA, since the date I am working with contains more then 400k rows. My Excel just stops working..

I would like to pass that CAT array to VBA function (e.g. CATEGORY) variable and then use it. Logic would be, that I read array (CAT) into 3-d array variable, e.g. CAT (CAT, MIN, MAX), then something like this

```
public function CATEGORY (CAT as array, VAL as double)
Dim CAT (CAT, MIN, MAX)
    for each CAT (CAT)
    if VAL Between CAT(MIN) and CAT(MAX) then CATEGORY=CAT(CAT)
Next CAT
```

Please help me to write VBA code to pass 3-d variable from table to VBA user-defined function and then use it.
Thanks!

Comment: A 2-D array would be cat(1 to 3, 1 to 3) and that seems to be what you have. It is **not** a 3-D array like cat(1 to 3, 1 to 3, 1 to 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with proper limit cases handling you could exploit `Application.Match` and `Application.Index`

```
Function CATEGORY(CAT As Variant, VAL As Double)
    CATEGORY = Application.index(CAT, 0, 1)(WorksheetFunction.Match(VAL, Application.index(CAT, 0, 2), True), 1)
End Function
```

which you would use in your "Main" sub as follows:

```
Sub main()
    Dim myData As Variant, icat As Long

    myData = Range("D4").Resize(3, 3).value2 ' as per your example I cut off headers row
    MsgBox "CAT for 42 is: " & CATEGORY(myData, 42)
    MsgBox "CAT for 16 is: " & CATEGORY(myData, 16)
    MsgBox "CAT for 2  is: " & CATEGORY(myData, 2)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume that the array is actually a 2-D array collected like,

```
dim arr as variant
arr = cells(2, "A").resize(3, 3).value2
```

Then the function becomes,

```
function CATEGORY (CAT as variant, VAL as double)
    dim i as long
    for i=lbound(cat, 1) to ubound(cat, 1)
        if val>=cat(i, 2) and val<=cat(i, 3) then
            CATEGORY = cat(i, 1)
            exit for
        end if
    next i
end function
```

Use it like,

```
dim arr as variant, icat as long
arr = cells(2, "A").resize(3, 3).value2
icat = CATEGORY(arr, 42)
debug.print icat
```